# git pull results in "does not appear to be a git repository"

Tags: git, azure, github

I'm trying to grab contents of [Windows Azure SDK](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net) to my local disk. I created a folder, `cd`d there, ran `git init`, now whenever I try either of the following:

```
git pull WindowsAzure
```

or

```
git pull WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net
```

or

```
git pull azure-sdk-for-net
```

I will always get an error message saying `[X] does not appear to be a git repository`.

What am I doing wrong and how do I pull the contents of that project to my local repo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Git has no way to recognize the name 'WindowsAzure' yet, as git can work with repositories other than those on github. You need to give it a URL for the repository first.

Run:

```
git clone https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net.git
```